# What has happened to Iona?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I became Thane of Riften and got Iona as a housecarl and I married. She was in my house but after a while she just disappeared from my house and isn't anywhere in riften, from what it seems. Any idea where she would be? I also have not gotten a letter from a courier to inform that she has been killed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PC, open the console with '~' and type "prid 000A2C93", enter, then type "moveto player"